# What is the best way to copy data from Hadoop to an external disk?

Tags: azure, hadoop, cloud

I have to move around 80TB data from Hadoop to Azure. I got 10 data disks from Azure which I can connect to the gateway node one at a time.

After connecting the azure disk to gateway node machine I run the following command :-

```
hdfs dfs -get /path/to/hdfs/dir /azuredisk1/
```

This is giving me a download speed of ~70 MB/s

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you not using WASB?

Comment: I am sorry if i did not understand the question. 

We use on prem Cloudera Hadoop currently and the objective is to move the data to Azure Blob Storage or WASB.

Comment: If you are using either of those, then you shouldn't be using `hdfs get`, you should use [`distcp`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) after configuring [Azure support](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/index.html)